# Can we run one scenario for list of object using Karate API

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

We are using Karate, to automate API.
Where In last I want to clean all the test data which has been created by Automation suite.
by using below scenario
- first we will get all the profiles which we have created thru automation
- and then we will execute delete API for each profileID

```
Scenarios till now :
    @DeleteAllProfile
    Scenario: Get Profile list -> Apply filter to ignore Default profile ->  Delete each Profile
        Given path '/profiles'
        When method GET
        Then status 200
       * def children = $response[*].profileId
```

Children is the object which consists all the profileID
for example :
 ["AutoProfileId758",
  "AutoProfileId169",
  "AutoProfileId90",
  "AutoProfile59",
  "AutoProfile10",
  "AutoProfile64",
  "AutoProfile44"
]

Now we need to call delete API on each profile,

```
        Given path '/profile/'+ x
        When method DELETE
        Then status 204
```

X  is the value which I want iterate from children object 
and length of x will be dynamic

Any method to achieve this?

I tried to write below code

```
    * def fun = function(x){
        Given path '/profile/'+ x
        When method DELETE
        Then status 204}

    * karate.forEach(children, fun)
```

But its doesn't work